# View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

The view below is gives me the error when using the POST method. I'm trying to load the model data into a form, allow the user to edit, and then update the database. When I try to Save the changes I get the above error.

```
def edit(request, row_id):
    rating = get_object_or_404(Rating, pk=row_id)
    context = {'form': rating}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RatingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home.html')
    else:
        return render(
            request,
            'ratings/entry_def.html',
            context
        )
```

Here is the trace from the terminal.

```
[15/Apr/2016 22:44:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1554
[15/Apr/2016 22:44:12] "GET /rating/edit/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 919
Internal Server Error: /rating/edit/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/michelecollender/ENVlag/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in get_response
    % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view ratings.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: There's no `return` if the form isn't valid

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Eli what would be an appropriate HttpResponse to return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redirecting if `form.is_valid()` but what about the form is invalid? There isn't any code that get's executed in this case? There's no code for that. When a function doesn't explicitly return a value, a caller that expects a return value is given `None`. Hence the error.

You could try something like this:

```
def edit(request, row_id):
    rating = get_object_or_404(Rating, pk=row_id)
    context = {'form': rating}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RatingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home.html')
        else :
            return render(request, 'ratings/entry_def.html', 
                          {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(
            request,
            'ratings/entry_def.html',
            context
        )
```

This will result in the form being displayed again to the user and if you have coded your template correctly it will show which fields are invalid.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Since you are a new user here, permit me to point out that if the problem is solved, it's customary to mark the answer as correct. This helps someone who lands on this page in the future from a google search.

Comment: aha! I was like how do you do that? but I got it. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I was with this same error, believe it or not, was the indentation of Python.

Answer (score 0):

your error to the indentation of a Python file. You have to be careful when following tutorials and/or copy-pasting code. Incorrect indentation can waste lot of valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Return What file you are rendering instead of Direct Render.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

def logout(request): 
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Add Import HttpRespose

from django.http import HttpResponse

And then Return it like
HttpResponse("Your Message)