# django passing arguments from template to bash script

Tags: python, mysql, django, bash

I am trying to have an input field in the template that the user enters a query and that query goes to the **views.py**
and from there i m taking the query and pass it as argument to the bash script.

This is what i have for now.
**views.py**

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            query = request.POST['query']
            test = subprocess.check_call(['home/.../bash.sh',
                                          query])
            return render(request, 'base.html', {'input': test})
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse("Nothing was submitted!")
```

**base.html**

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="{{ input }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am stuck right here..i don't know if i shout *request.POST* or something else much simpler...cause i don't want to use a form.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to populate the form with query results?

Comment: i just want to enter the query in that input field and the query goes to the bash script...but the page is not working...i get  this  ***ValueError: The view crawler.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.***

Comment: Probably a setup issue, i.e. something is not pointing to the right place. Do other pages work?

Comment: yes...everything works fine..including calling the bash script... i even tested the function **home** with just a **HttpResponse** return...without the request.method

Comment: Looks like an invalid form, checkout this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657955/view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead

Comment: i don't have a form **forms.py**  do i really need to create one? i only need the user input to go to the views.py

Comment: No, it looks like your base.html is already sending something to views. Try   is_valid method to check if form is OK, just like in the post I sent above.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out by creating a script in the html template.

```
<script>
    $(".opener").click(function () {
        var thead = $("#mytable").find("thead");
        thead.find('th').last().remove();
        thead = thead.html();
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');
        row.find('td').last().remove();
        row = row.html();
        var table = $(document.createElement('table'));
        table.append('<thead>' + thead + '</thead>');
        table.append('<tbody><tr>' + row + '</tr></tbody>')
        $(".modal").html("").append(table);
        $(".modal").dialog({width: 'auto', position: 'top'});
    });
</script>
```