# Trying to connect Django to Payfort with an API .(Payment gateway integration). when i run the pay.html it gives me a value error in my views file

Tags: python, django, http, render, payfort

**Error is :ValueError: The view hadid.views.initiate_payment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Exception Location: C:\Users\Chaims music\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 124

I am adding my def initiate_payment below

```
def initiate_payment(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, 'templates/pay.html')
 try:
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    amount = int(request.POST['amount'])
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
        raise ValueError
    auth_login(request=request, user=user)
except:
    return render(request, 'templates/pay.html', context={'error': 'Wrong Account Details or amount'})

transaction = Transaction.objects.create(made_by=user, amount=amount)
transaction.save()
```

This is just the initiate_payment where the error is coming from. please help i already tried [similiar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657955/view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead)

if any other file is needed let me know .

any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has to return a response, you return render(...) in your except block but you don’t return anything  in the try block

Comment: i am trying to return something below the try statement but when i do that it makes my (transaction = Transaction.objects.create(made_by=user, amount=amount)) line "unreachable". what should i do ?

Comment: Just put your transaction code inside try block before you return.